# Are academics considered "experts", "professionals", or both in their scientific field?

Tags: word-usage

I wrote a proposal for a survey to be conducted at a conference in the field of requirements engineering. I decided that all attendants at the conference, both the ones coming from industry and ones coming from academia, will be a good target population. I don't remember which word I used in the proposal, "RE experts" or "RE professionals" or both, because for me, both words apply to anybody who attends a conference in the field and are practically synonyms in this context.

In one of the reviews, the reviewer seems to make a distinction:

> For example, the RQ’s talk about the RE community and RE experts rather than professionals (e.g., what about researchers who may be experts but not professionals)

So my questions are

1. what is the actual distinction between an expert and a professional in such a setting?
2. Why would an academic researcher not be considered a professional?

This is maybe clear to native English speakers, but not to me, and I will probably have to use the terms frequently in my thesis, so I need the clarification.

Comment: A professional requirements engineer is someone who earns a living as a requirements engineer - whatever that is. An academic would be employed by a university so would not be described as a professional requirements engineer.

Comment: @TheMathemagician but requirements engineering professors (and their grad students) create requirements specifications in the course of their work just like medical professors do surgery. If you don't know what RE is - would you say that a medicine professor is not a medicine professional because he doesn't get paid to do medicine, even if he does do surgery and gets paid for it?

Comment: I'm not here to debate the semantics... I've told you the reason academics would not be classed as professionals. They are employed as professors, lecturers, TAs whatever NOT engineers.

Comment: @TheMathemagician but my question is exactly about the semantics of the two words, this is why I assumed that you are debating them :)

Comment: A researcher might be professional (adjective) but would not normally be considered a professional (noun). The latter is about the primary focus of your work, and if that's research rather than the everyday practice of your profession, then you are an academic rather than a professional.

Answer (score 1):

A professor of medicine has usually gained considerable expertise in his field (e.g. not every cardiologist becomes a Professor of Cardiology). In addition, most professors of medicine still do medicine in a limited manner, usually in a teaching setting.

The same with surgery: there are those who do it for their living, and those who, after having done it, choose to go into academics and become professors.

In medicine, an "expert" is someone who sub-specializes in one field (or, rarely, two), because the field of medicine is too broad to b an expert in the whole. There are general surgeons, and while they may be *expert*, in this context, it means very skilled. Among sub-specialties in surgery are thoracic surgery, neurosurgery or heart surgery. They need not be professors (in fact, practitioners usually make far more money than Professors.) Some, though, place knowledge above practice, and become Professors/researchers at leading medical institutions (Johns Hopkins or Harvard).

I don't see that this helps you. I'd say, though, that **professors are academics while both are experts in their fields**.

I am a practitioner in a general field. I do not consider myself an expert, although it took me an additional 4 years of studying after becoming a doctor to become board certified in my field. The sub-specialists usually put in seven years or more.

Comment: OP's asking about "professional", not professor.

Comment: OP asked about medical professors and professionals in comments.

Comment: I was just going off the question....

Comment: I used "professor" as an example for "academic" in the comment, but really wanted to know the difference between "professional" and "expert"; I know what a "professor" is.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the field of English Language (and Usage). There are those who are experts (having studied and thought about the subject deeply) but whose profession is law, philosophy or something else.  There are also English teachers who rely on ill-digested maxims and half-understood lecture notes; they are not experts, but by virtue of their monthly pay cheque they are English professionals.

And a wise man once said that *expert* is not a title you can claim for yourself: it has to be awarded by others.

Answer (score -1):

Strictly speaking, a professional is someone who is well-educated and self-employed. For example, doctors (who do not work for a practice), lawyers (ditto) and consulting engineers are professionals, but their counterparts, who are paid a salary, are not.

An expert is simply someone who knows an extraordinary amount about some subject. While experts are usually academics (and academics are not professionals) they don't have to be: experts in types of railway trains are usually laymen, while experts in insect classification are usually academics.

Comment: Hi, Simon. Can you cite an authoritative source that supports your view of a professional as (strictly speaking) someone well-educated **and** self-employed? Merriam-Webster doesn't make that distinction in discussing the noun or adjective form of _professional_. For example, it gives as one relevant definition of the adjective "engaged in one of the learned professions": and one of its definitions of _profession_ is "a calling requiring specialized knowledge and often long and intensive academic profession." Neither definition makes self-employment a prerequisite for being a professional.

Comment: Hello Sven, Perhaps I was being excessively dogmatic in my previous post, but I believe my point stands. For example, the Wikipedia entry about this subject ("profession") emphasises that professionals must _necessarily_ provide _independent_ and _unbiased_ advice, which can be difficult to guarantee when you're employed by a company with a financial interest in your opinion. (The self-employment requirement is also consistent with the word's origins in religious orders and the law.) I'm sorry that I cannot provide a more reliable source; the Wikipedia is hardly a gold standard for info!!

Comment: Fair enough. Thanks for considering my suggestion—and welcome to the English Language & Usage site.